# How do I test for a powered lever in Minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to have a system that will power a set of commands when a wall lever (facing south) is powered, and I want it to power a different set of commands when the lever isn't powered. I know this can be done with /execute, but I do not know how. =(

Comment: I would also like to do the same thing with buttons in a diff part of my map

Comment: Have you researched anywhere else online?  You'll find that the community will be more receptive if you've shown some effort in trying to solve your problem first.  A good first stop might be the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/execute)

Comment: It's pretty much the same in 1.13, just the new command syntax and block state instead of a number. But block states also existed before, so that's also nothing new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same question, but figured it out through experimentation. Unless it is absolutely essential that the lever be facing south, you can get by with just  "/execute if block (Position of Lever) minecraft:lever[powered=true] run (Command)". If it does need to be facing south, change [powered=true] to [powered=true,facing=south].